# Azure webapp credentials to one project change another project username

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have multiple directory (i.e. Account) added to my account and having multiple web apps available in different directories.

When I have changed the user credentials in one web app under a directory, the user name get changed for another directory web app user name as well.

This could be a red alert to me since each apps have to be deployed individually by different users.

Needed to resolve this issue as I have no time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's how it works. I assume you are taking about about Account Credentials which you can change in the "Deployment Credentials" blade of the Setting section. If you change these credentials, they will impact all the App Services of that Account (all subscriptions within that account).

As your requirement is to provide different credentials for different developers who maintain those app services, I suggest you to use the credentials that you get from the "Get Publish Profile" link. these credentials are specific to that particular app service. they will not change until you click on "Reset Publish Profile".

[image]

For more information about different type of Credentials, please have a look [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-app-service-deployment-types-and-ftp-credential-types/).

Thanks,
Prawin